# how to view pdf inside the app from url

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

Guys i want to view the pdf file from url i have done some coding stuff but getting error .Please help me out.If there is another solution please give an suggestion

```
          @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  Button  button = (Button) findViewById( R.id.mybutt );

    String pdf = "http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf";
    String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf;'></iframe>";
WebView  wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
wv.loadUrl(doc);
}
```

Layout

```
        <WebView
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/webView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: check this lib https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: Make also sure to change the url for the pdf to an existing pdf (currently not the case).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply load url in webview no need of iframe.
String pdf = "http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf";
wv.loadUrl(pdf);

Use these free open source lib for pdf loading.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/droidreader/
https://code.google.com/archive/p/apv/

Answer (score 0):

Append your PDF URL after this

```
String pdfUrl="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<PDF_URL>";
```

Replace  by your PDF url then

```
wv.loadUrl(pdfUrl);
```

Like this

```
String pdfUrl="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your doc string URL from

```
String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf;'></iframe>";
```

To

```
String doc="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.pc-hardware.hu/PDF/konfig.pdf"
```

Make sure that PDF is exist at url parameter path.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the PDF is public.. you can use the google doc url.

Example,

```
public void showPdf(MarketStudy marketStudy) {
        String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=";
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, WebviewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL",googleDocsUrl+Uri.encode(marketStudy.getPath()));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
}
```

But if the PDF is from the private server, you cant view it by using the googledoc url. or else it will show "no preview" message eventhough the pdf is exists. (My Case)..
I already tried using `<iframe>`, `<object>`, WebView.. none is working.. 
so my solution for you is use this library [MultithreadDownload](https://github.com/Aspsine/MultiThreadDownload) and [AndroidPDFViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) where you need to download it store in cache folder first and then display it on activity then delete it when activity stop or destroy.

Hope it helps..